# Pandas pivot table and np.sum

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to pivot a pandas dataframe (read from csv file. size 16.3 MB)

```
pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Column1', 'Column2'], columns=['Column3'], values=['value1', 'value2', 'value3'], aggfunc=np.sum)
```

This is the error that I get -

```
ValueError: array is too big; `arr.size * arr.dtype.itemsize` is larger than the maximum possible size.
```

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you attach `df.head()` to your question?

Comment: There is error if change `aggfunc=np.sum` to `aggfunc='sum'` ?

Comment: @jezrael I would be very surprised it that worked, can you explain a bit on the rationale?

Comment: @iDrwish - I hope pandas return nicer error like numpy error ;)

Comment: hmmm, I think problem should be too large numbers, because is used `sum` - check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51621963)

Comment: The pivot table array will have a size of `len(df.groupby(['Column1','Column2'])) * len(df.groupby(['Column3']))`, this size is obviously too big for your memory.

Comment: @Stef, yes the table is huge. Can you please suggest some alternative?

Comment: if the whole table doesn't fit into memory, may you can do it by groups of columns in parts ([dask pivot table](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html?highlight=pivot#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.pivot_table) is of no help here as it only supports a single index column)